# Can I cure Vilkas even if he's my spouse? If yes, how?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I married Vilkas a few skyrim months ago, and just learned he could be cured of lycanthropy. How do I cure him as my spouse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes I believe you can =. Some requirements should be met.

- You must have at least one Glenmoril Witch Head in your inventory.

  - You must complete at least one Radiant Quest from Vilkas, after completing "Glory of the Dead" with a Glenmoril Witch Head in your inventory.

This could also be a glitch